# inquiring about a subject of a sentence that you've just overheard

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine you have just entered a room and saw your friends talking about something. One of you friends is finishing her sentence (your friends are talking about aircraft, but you don't know that):

> They all go to boneyard and stay there for good after they become too old.

You really want to know who "they" in this sentence are. From "stay at boneyard for good" you infer that the subject is inanimate things, rather than humans or animals.

So how would you ask of your friends a question that will help you find out the subject of their conversation?

1) Who goes to boneyard after it becomes too old?

2) What goes to boneyard after it becomes too old?

3) Who goes to boneyard after they become too old?

4) Who go to boneyard after they become too old?

5) What goes to boneyard after they become too old?

6) What go to boneyard after they become too old?

7) [something else?]

(I understand that I can simply ask "What are you guys talking about?", but I want to respond to the last sentence spoken by my friend)

Comment: First of all, unless there is some place with the name of *Boneyard*, you really need to use an article. It should be ***a*** *boneyard* or ***the*** *boneyard*. And it's also *goes*, not *go*; *who* and *what* both take a singular verb if the subject is unknown.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "who and what both take a singular verb if the subject is unknown" - What if the subject is unknown, but it's know that it is plural (like in my question)?

Comment: The plurality doesn't matter in any of the specific sentences in the question; they all have a construction that uses a singular form. However, for comparison, here is a construction where you *could* use a plural subject: *Who **are** all of **the people** who **go** to the boneyard after **they** become too old?* (And the answer would be a list of people in some form.) But also note that in that question it's known that the subject is *people*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "they all have a construction that uses a singular form" - I am afraid I would have to disagree with this assertion. Sentences 4 and 6 use "go", not "goes", in other words, they use plural form.

Comment: The construction I was taking about was putting *who* or *what* at the start of the sentences, as well as the other grammatical elements that they use. All of that combined makes the use of *go* simply wrong. You can't claim it's right because it *was* used. If that were a meaningful argument, then there would never be anything ungrammatical.

Comment: @JasonBassford - In your sentence "who" is also placed at the very start ("Who are all of the people who go to the boneyard after they become too old?"), and yet it's perfectly grammatical and "who" there is plural. It's like in case with some nouns that just like "who" and "what" may be singular or plural depending on the context: "Deer lives in the forest", "Sheep goes out of the pen" - "deer" and "sheep" are singular; "Deer live in the forest", "Sheep go out of the pen" - "deer" and "sheep" are plural.

Comment: Yes, and I also said *as well as other grammatical elements*. If you want to know *why* your sentences should not use the plural form, then you should ask that as a separate question. Any explanation is beyond the ability of comments to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "What were you talking about" or "I'm sorry, I missed the start, what was the subject of discussion" Are **far** more natural ways to ask this question -- repeating much of the sentence as your examples do tends to sound stilted.

That said, if you understand the discussion to be about inanimate objects, your example 2 (or possibly 5) are the only correct options. 1, 3, & 4 are eliminated because "who" is not used for non-persons. 6 is eliminated because "what go" does not agree in number.

A possible 7: "What is being sent to the boneyard, please?"